# Making a Copy of Reference itself?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way that let me make a copy of a reference itself? For example, I've a ListView control added on the form and I want to persist its Items Collection i.e.

```
ListViewItemCollection lvic = ListView.Items();
```

and when i call **ListView.Items.Clear()**, lvic should not be cleared.

Comment: You're already copying the reference with that statement. I think you want to copy the collection that's being referenced, not the reference itself.

Comment: I just need to preserve the Items Collection so that I can access it after the collection is being cleared.

Comment: Then make a copy of the collection's items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning / copying is a wide subject. It really depends on the scenario. In you case, you can simply make a copy of the collection using Linq

```
ListViewItem[] copiedItems = ListView.Items().OfType<ListViewItem>().ToArray();
```

Be carefull with cloning in this scenario. an instance of ListViewItemCollection can't be assigned to a ListView and a copy of ListView or ListViewItem still uses some native resources (in the winforms and wpf world) so copying will lead to terrible bugs when used wrongly

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to try

```
  ListViewItem[] items = new ListViewItem[listView1.Items.Count];
  listView1.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);
```

OR

You need to create the clone of the object for that you can check this post which discuss about the cloning of the object : [Cloning in C#.NET.](http://www.codekicks.com/2009/04/cloning-in-cnet.html)

There are two type of cloning which is discuss in the article

```
1. Deep Cloning
2. Shallow Copy
```

Comment: LOL, shallow clone instead of shadow